# Android widget сбрасывает данные

Tags: android, android-widgets

В приложении имеется обычный виджет с тремя `TextView`. Из `SharedPreferences` загружаются данные, которые обрабатываются в методах и результат обработки заносится в `TextView`. После перезагрузки телефона все данные скидываются в единицы и виджет перестает быть кликабельным. Проблема решается после обновления виджета через указанное в настройках время. Так же данная проблема была замечена на слабом телефоне, при переносе виджета с одного экрана на другой. Подскажите, как с этим бороться?

Класс виджета:

```
public class NewAppWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
SharedPreferences mSettings;

void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId) {
    loadSettings(context); //загрузка данных из SP

    RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.template_widget);
    views.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_time_value, getDays(context));

    RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.template_widget);
    views2.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_count_value, getCount());

    RemoteViews views3 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.template_widget);
    views3.setTextViewText(R.id.appwidget_money_value, getMoney());

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pIntentMainActivity = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget, pIntentMainActivity);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views2);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views3);
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId);
    }
}

@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}
```

Провайдер

```
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/template_widget"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/template_widget"
    android:minHeight="20dp"
    android:minWidth="120dp"
    android:resizeMode="horizontal"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/example_appwidget_preview"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen">
</appwidget-provider>
```

Comment: А для чего Вы несколько раз получаете объект RemoteViews views, а потом еще и для каждого вызываете обновление. Это ведь один и тот же объект.
И не забудьте в onUpdate Добавить вызов родительского метода:
super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

Comment: Спасибо, вроде заработало как надо. Можете оформить коммент как ответ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объект класса `RemoteViews` получать несколько раз не имеет смысла, потому что это одно и то же.

Так же необходимо в `onUpdate` добавить вызов родительского метода `super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);`